# Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have this code in my index.js

```
...
import userRoutes from './src/routes/userRoutes';
import invoicesRoutes from './src/routes/invoicesRoutes';
import authMiddleware from "./src/middlewares/authMiddleware";
...
const app = express();
...
app.use('/user', authMiddleware, userRoutes(app));
app.use('/invoices', authMiddleware, invoicesRoutes(app));
```

my authmiddleware

```
const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'JWT') {
        console.log(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0]);
        next();
    } else {
        console.log('else');
        next();
    }
};

export default authMiddleware;
```

and one of my routes:

```
import { register, login } from '../controllers/authController';

const userRoutes = (app) => {
    app.route('/user/signup')
        .post(register);
    app.route('/user/login')
        .post(login);
};

export default userRoutes;
```

I'm getting an error:

> throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but
>   got a ' + gettype(fn))
>         ^
>
> TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a
>   undefined

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass your routes initialization as a middleware fuction
`app.use('/user', authMiddleware, userRoutes(app));`

In this line of code what `userRoutes(app)` was supposed to return is `function(req,res[,next]){}`

Its should be like this

```
app.use('/user', authMiddleware, (req, res, next) => {
        userRoutes(app);
        next()
})
```

and what you do is

```
app.use('/user', authMiddleware, (app) => {
    app.route('/user/signup').post(register);
    app.route('/user/login').post(login);
})
```

that is wrong

There seems to be some bad logic here because from what I understand  you will have to call `http://localhost/user` to initialize the routes and that will not work well beacuse of express's middleware inclusion.

Again from what I understand what you are trying to do should look more like this

```
...
import userRoutes from './src/routes/userRoutes';
import invoicesRoutes from './src/routes/invoicesRoutes';
...
const app = express();
userRoutes(app);
invoicesRoutes(app);
```

and

```
import { register, login } from '../controllers/authController';
import authMiddleware from "./middleware";
const userRoutes = (app) => {
    app.post('/user/signup', authMiddleware, register);
    app.post('/user/login', authMiddleware, login);
};

export default userRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Express already offer the [Router class](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express.Router) to separate routes in different sub-modules, So you can import `userRoutes` module without passing `app` variable into it, here is an example:

**userRoutes.js**

```
import { register, login } from '../controllers/authController';
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.route('/signup')
        .post(register);

router.route('/login')
        .post(login);

export default router;
```

**index.js**

```
...
import userRoutes from './src/routes/userRoutes';
import invoicesRoutes from './src/routes/invoicesRoutes';
import authMiddleware from "./src/middlewares/authMiddleware";
...
const app = express();
...
app.use('/user', authMiddleware, userRoutes);
app.use('/invoices', authMiddleware, invoicesRoutes);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check all your JavaScript files to make sure you are not missing this line:

```
module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

In my route.js

I had put it like this
`module.exports = routes;`

what I intended to do was export routes, after changing it like below my error was gone
`module.exports = {routes};`